# NSTextView won't become first responder

Tags: cocoa, nstextview, first-responder

Here's the layout of my little test app:

1. `AppDelegate` owns `WindowController`.
2. `WindowController` owns `CustomTextContainerView`.
3. `CustomTextContainerView` owns an `NSScrollView` which embeds `MyCustomTextView` (an `NSTextView` subclass).

The xibs for both the standard `MainMenu` and my window controller are relatively empty. My window controller's `-windowDidLoad` looks like this:

```
- (void)windowDidLoad {
    [super windowDidLoad];
    // create CustomTextContainerView
    [[self window] setContentView:self.customTextContainerView];
}
```

What I'm trying to do is **set first responder** to the textView, but I've tried everything I can think of to get this to work.

I've made it so `CustomTextContainerView` just forwards `-becomeFirstResponder` on to its textView. I've tried calling it directly on both the container and the textView but I can't get it to become first responder automatically.

**Note:** The user can still click in the text area and start typing, but what I'm trying to do is set first responder status automatically so I don't have to click before I start typing. What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To force the first responder for a window, call this:

```
[[self window] makeFirstResponder:self.customTextContainerView];
```

(This assumes that everything else necessary for first-responder status is enabled, e.g. the view can't have overridden `acceptsFirstResponder` to return `NO`.)

Comment: The solution (which I found independently actually :)) ended up being a combination of calling this on the window *and* adding my container view as a subview of the Window's `contentView` instead of setting it **as** the contentView.